# How to know here table is locked or not?

Tags: mysql

from innodb engine status ,we observed below statement.
Below statement means the table already in lock or query is trying to lock?

TABLE LOCK table `xct`.`zfdf` trx id FB61C0B lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 563 page no 4504 n bits 344 index `PRIMARY` of table `xct`.`zfdf` trx id Skc98B lock_mode X locks rec but not gap

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html